# Nginx slow static file serving after a period of inactivity

Tags: performance, nginx, response, openresty

I have a nginx server deployed as a reverse proxy. everything works great if I regularly use the service.
Issue happens when the nginx service that I have deployed is inactive or not used(NO REQUEST PROCOSSED) for few days.
When I try to launch THE application using nginx the static files download take lots of time even though the size of the files are in byte.
issues goes away after I restart my nginx SERVER.

Using 1.15.8.3 version of openresty.

any suggestion/help will be highly appreciated.